# In python how to replace a string placed between string and special character

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

I wanted to replace the below-highlighted string with just a {. Kindly share your thoughts

Strings between '{' and '}]' has to replaced with {

I have stored to below json to str to perform replace

```
{'preview': False, 'init_offset': 0, 'messages': [], 'fields': [{'name': 'dxx.jxx.lxx.sxx'}, {'name': 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName'}, {'name': 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx'}, {'name': 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status'}], 'results': [{'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-07T05:44:46.817Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '87', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}, {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-06T22:29:28.966Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '56772655863572929', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}, {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-05T20:21:30.062Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '43', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}, {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-04T03:05:24.848Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '54', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}, {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-04T03:05:23.610Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '53', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}, {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-03T07:33:00.594Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '23', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}], 'highlighted': {}}
```

Expected output:

```
{'results': [{'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-07T05:44:46.817Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '87', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}, {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-06T22:29:28.966Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '56772655863572929', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}, {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-05T20:21:30.062Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '43', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}, {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-04T03:05:24.848Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '54', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}, {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-04T03:05:23.610Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '53', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}, {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-03T07:33:00.594Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '23', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}], 'highlighted': {}}
```

I have tried:

```
s = re.sub('^*}], ', '{', s)
print(s)
```

Comment: Could you add any example code?

Comment: @RubénPozo, Below is the code i tried. Thanks ! 
s = re.sub('^*}],  ', '{', s)
print s

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you hoping to do with `{'results': }`?

Comment: `re.sub('^.*}], ', '{', s)` Note the `.` after the `^` in the regex. `^` matches string-start. `^*` is an [invalid regex](https://regex101.com/r/gAFTuF/2) because you cannot have multiple string-starts in the same string. The `.` gives the `*` something to quantify, [so it works](https://regex101.com/r/gAFTuF/3)

Comment: @JonSG, results hold the array of key-value pairs.  I am trying to eliminate "{'preview': False, 'init_offset': 0, 'messages': [], 'fields': [{'name': 'data.jxx.sxx'}, {'name': 'data.xx.xx'}, {'name': 'data.jxx.txx'}, {'name': 'data.jxx.lxx.status'}]," and take the key, value pairs from "results" to form a expected json response.

Comment: What exact output are you hoping for though? Since `{ 'results': }` is neither valid json nor valid ast I am wondering what you plan to do with it. If you just omitted a bunch of what results actually is then there might be trivial ways to use `ast` or `json` to give you the result you seek.

Comment: @JonSG Added the complete data under "The original data". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the full anticipated output makes the question easier to solve. It appears as though you just want a couple of keys from your json/dict.

So if we have:

```
data_in = {
    'preview': False,
    'init_offset': 0,
    'messages': [],
    'fields': [
        {'name': 'dxx.jxx.lxx.sxx'},
        {'name': 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName'},
        {'name': 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx'},
        {'name': 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status'}
    ],
    'results': [
        {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-07T05:44:46.817Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '87', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'},
        {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-06T22:29:28.966Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '56772655863572929', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'},
        {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-05T20:21:30.062Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '43', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'},
        {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-04T03:05:24.848Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '54', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'},
        {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-04T03:05:23.610Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '53', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'},
        {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-03T07:33:00.594Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '23', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}
    ],
    'highlighted': {}
}
```

and we expect:

```
data_expected = {
    'results': [
        {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-07T05:44:46.817Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '87', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'},
        {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-06T22:29:28.966Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '56772655863572929', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'},
        {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-05T20:21:30.062Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '43', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'},
        {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-04T03:05:24.848Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '54', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'},
        {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-04T03:05:23.610Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '53', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'},
        {'dxxx.jxxx.log.startTime': '2021-06-03T07:33:00.594Z', 'dxxx.jxxx.operationName': 'testops', 'dxxx.jxxx.txxx': '23', 'dxxx.jxxx.log.payload.status': '200'}
    ],
    'highlighted': {}
}
```

We can test that this simple comprehension does the trick for us:

```
data_out = {key:value for key, value in data_in.items() if key in ("results", "highlighted")}
isMatching = json.dumps(data_expected) == json.dumps(data_out)
print(f"data_out matches data_expected: { isMatching }")
```

Note that you will also need an:

```
import json
```

If you want to do that test above.

Note that if the **only** key you want is the `results` key, then all you need is:

```
data_out = {"results": [item for item in data_in["results"]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In brief, `^` matches beginning of line, `*` matches "zero or more of the previous expression" i.e. "beginnings of line", though I don't think repetitions of `^` are well-defined. The remainder of the expression just matches literally.

If we can guess what you hoped for it to match, perhaps try

```py
s = re.sub(r'^\{.*}], ', '{', s)
```

`{` is a regex metacharacter, so it needs to be backslash-escaped to match literally.

Comment: thank you for the response. My bad, under the question I have included the complete data under "The original data".. When I add and execute "s = re.sub(r'^\{.*}], ', '{', s)", the output am getting is {'highlighted': {}}

that's because, in question, I haven't the complete data under results

Comment: The proper solution in such cases is to accept an answer which solves your _actual_ question, and the post a new question with your real requirements if you still need help. Editing a question so that it invalidates existing answers is not acceptable.